# Why SqlTrackingService doesn't work with WF 4.0?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, tracking

In Workflow Foundation 3.5 we could track data with SqlTrackingService, but in WF it doesn't work: when trying to use it SqlTrackingService doesn't catch any workflow or activity event.

*Is there any way to configure SqlTrackingService in WF 4.0 without writing custom tracing service?* The point is I want to use as much built-in tools as possible (like WorkflowMonitor from the MS samples)

Here are two examples:

**WF3.5** (works perfectly, notice that My3Activity must be compiled as .NET 3.5 Workflow Activity Library)

```
namespace WfServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating workflow runtime...");
            using (WorkflowRuntime wr = new WorkflowRuntime())
            {
                SqlTrackingService ts = new SqlTrackingService("Initial Catalog=Tracking;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                ts.UseDefaultProfile = true;

                wr.AddService(ts);

                wr.StartRuntime();

                Console.WriteLine("Creating workflow instance...");
                WorkflowInstance wi = wr.CreateWorkflow(typeof(My3Activity));

                Console.WriteLine("Starting workflow instance...");
                wi.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow instance started");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to STOP");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow runtime stopped.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**WF4.0** (doesn't raise any events or probably they are not catched by tracking service; this time MyActivity is .NET 4.0 WF Activity Library)

```
namespace WfServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating workflow runtime...");
            using (WorkflowRuntime wr = new WorkflowRuntime())
            {
                SqlTrackingService ts = new SqlTrackingService("Initial Catalog=Tracking;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                ts.UseDefaultProfile = true;

                wr.AddService(ts);

                wr.StartRuntime();

                Console.WriteLine("Creating workflow instance...");
                MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
                WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(activity);

                Console.WriteLine("Starting workflow instance...");
                app.Run();
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow instance started");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to STOP");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow runtime stopped.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation between WF3 and WF4. The latter is a complete rewrite and doesn't share any types with the previous WF3. As a result the SqlTrackingService in .NET 4 only works with the WF3.

Your second code example is an interesting mix of WF3 and WF4 types. The WorkflowApplication is WF4 while the WorkflowRuntime used is WF3. Maixing these doesn't make any sense at all.

If it is intended to be WF4 the code should look something like this:

```
namespace WfServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating workflow instance...");
            MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
            WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(activity);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting workflow instance...");
            app.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow instance started");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to STOP");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```